# Run a post-build script from brunch

Tags: brunch

I need to run a system script after a brunch build (either manually built or with brunch watch). Is there a good way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plugin that will have [`onCompile` method](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/plugins.md).

See example plugin https://github.com/steffenmllr/imageoptmizer-brunch/blob/master/src/index.coffee

Comment: thanks for the response. I did exactly what you said and used your brunch plugin boilerplate to make it easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to install the [after-brunch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/after-brunch) NPM package that exposes a config point where you can insert command line scripts.